# Artemis actimeMQ error on start up (Windows)

Tags: windows, activemq-artemis

After installing artemis in Windows and create a broker in C:\var\lib\mybroker

I got an error on the server just after the logging in the http://localhost:8161/console

```
2018-03-23 16:59:08,469 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224085: Failed to load property PropsFile=C:\var\lib\mybroker\bin\file:\C:\var\lib\mybroker\etc\artemis-roles.properties, reason: file:\C:\var\lib\mybroker\etc\artemis-roles.properties (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect): java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\var\lib\mybroker\etc\artemis-roles.properties (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.ReloadableProperties.load(ReloadableProperties.java:99) [artemis-server-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.ReloadableProperties.obtained(ReloadableProperties.java:53) [artemis-server-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.PropertiesLoader.load(PropertiesLoader.java:52) [artemis-server-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.PropertiesLoginModule.initialize(PropertiesLoginModule.java:67) [artemis-server-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:736) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
        at io.hawt.system.Authenticator.doAuthenticate(Authenticator.java:131) [hawtio-system-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
```

The file exists, I'm pretty sure this happens because of file:\C:\var\lib\mybroker\etc\artemis-roles.properties

Shodl be file:/C:/var/lib/mybroker/etc/artemis-roles.properties

But I don't see how to configure this in config files on the server...

Comment: What version of Artemis are you using?  If you're not using the recently released 2.5 can you try that version?

Comment: I'm using that version. The last one released

Comment: How are you starting the broker?

Comment: With the comman artemis run

Comment: There's Windows-specific files like etc/artemis.cmd and etc/artemis.cmd.profile which contain system properties and path definitions. The error is probably there. I don't have a Windows box or VM set up so I can't test it at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you replaced the wrong part at artemis.profile.cmd regarding 
`-Djava.security.auth.login.config=%ARTEMIS_INSTANCE%\login.config`
by changing to
`-Djava.security.auth.login.config=%ARTEMIS_INSTANCE_ETC_URI%\login.config`

Indeed you need to point to the *etc* directory ( I run into the same issue) but not as a URI.
try this:
`-Djava.security.auth.login.config=%ARTEMIS_INSTANCE%\etc\login.config`